# How to add extra text to Query results?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet with data that a Google Form is continually adding data to. Once the data is added, there is a subset that I need to have sectioned off to another sheet.

I'm transposing the data so it sorts vertically for each Form's data, and the problem I'm running into is that I want each vertical selection to be individually labeled with the same consistent labels and I don't think I can make `CONCATENATE` work in this case (I would love to be proven wrong!).

Here's a link to the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1efOQRlKaJlffMnLd8f8oPZxJ57wVFGwKwVY3UW0savc/edit?usp=sharing

Here's the formula I currently have in `A1` on the `'Credential Request Form'` sheet:

`=TRANSPOSE(QUERY('Onboarding Form Responses'!A2:J,"Select F,B,C,D,G,A where A is not null order by A desc"))`

This presents the data I want and in the order I want it, but without labels before the data (sorry, "label" might be the wrong word here). I've included an example of how I'd like the data to present in cells `A9:A13` on the same sheet.

Is it possible to add those labels without a substantial amount of scripting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No scripting needed.

You can use a similar formula for your needs:

```
=TRANSPOSE(query(ARRAYFORMULA({"Employee Name:  "&'Onboarding Form Responses'!B2:B, 
                               "Store Number: "&'Onboarding Form Responses'!F2:F, 
                               "Parking Space: "&'Onboarding Form Responses'!G2:G}), 
                                    "Select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 is not null order by Col1 desc"))
```

[image]

Notice that we use `"Employee Name:  "&'Onboarding Form Responses'!B2:B` etc. for our ranges and then `Col1`, `Col2`, etc.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I wound up changing the query to ```"Select * where Col1 is not null order by Col6 desc"```, but it was the ```ARRAYFORMULA``` part I was missing. Thanks again!

Comment: One thing I had to add to make the dates work is `TEXT`, as in: `=TRANSPOSE(query(ARRAYFORMULA({"Employee Birthdate: "&(TEXT('Onboarding Form Responses'!C2:C, "mm/dd/yyyy"}))).`